# fminbound gets stuck in flat region

Tags: python, scipy

I want to solve `f(x) = 0`, hence I defined `g(x) = f(x)**2` and let `fminbound` run over `g(x)`.

Here's the pickle: As you will see, I have theoretical boundaries for `x`, but these are somewhat wide under some parameter specifications. Apparently, sometimes, `fminbound` gets stuck on the flat region and doesnt find the solution. What could I do here?

Here's the plot over `f(x)` for `[0, 1.5]`. The boundary I set up in `fminbound` are `[0, 2]`, but `f(x)` stays flat after 1.5:

[image: f(x)]

Comment: Think of the optimization routine as a short-sighted 2d wandering stick figure on your function who is trying to find the lowest point. After each step he is looking to the left and to the right to determine which step he wants to take next. If left and right is completely flat this does not work anymore. For numerical minimization the starting point is crucial. As this seems to be just a very simple 1d function, you can e.g. start with a simple bisection routine to find a good position to start.